# How to remove the file path from the Code Runner (VS Code extension) run command for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

When using the VS Code extension *Code Runner* for my C# .NET 6 console app, after hitting the run button, the following command runs in the terminal:

> ```
> ❯ dotnet run "/home/USER/code/c#/MyApp/Program.cs"
> Hello, World!
> ~/code/c#/MyApp ❯
> ```

I am wondering how to remove the file path after '`dotnet run`'. Given that I am already in the console application directory, I would like for the extension to only execute the '`dotnet run`' command, which would achieve the same result. I can demonstrate this by running the command myself without including the file path to the *'Program.cs'* file at the end:

> ```
> ❯ dotnet run
> Hello, World!
> ~/code/c#/MyApp ❯
> ```

This is purely an aesthetic matter, but it has been bugging me a lot and I've spent more than two hours now trying to figure out a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Press Ctrl (or Cmd) + Shift + P in VSCode
2. Type `settings json`
3. Click on `User Settings (JSON)`
4. Add `"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,`

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the solution is quite simple, just add a comment sign '**#**' to the end of the command that the Code Runner will run.

The commands themselves can be found in settings.json, namely in the executorMap field, which is an object whose keys specify the programming language and the command itself that Code Runner will execute in the terminal depending on the file extension.

By default, if you don't use any of Code Runner's standard variables (which can be found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)), for some reason it adds the full path to the file at the end of the command, so it would be logical to comment out this path.

Example:

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "csharp": "dotnet run #",
    "c": "make -s #",
    "cpp": "make -s #",
    "javascript": "bun $fullFileName",
    "typescript": "bun $fullFileName"
},
```

Answer (score -1):

**- Press ctrl + shift + P in VS Code

- Type settings.json
- click on user settings (Json)
- Add "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,**

Comment: How is this different from the existing answer?